# Loading two JFrame at once

Tags: java, swing, serversocket

Recently i'm developing client/server apps in java.

I have two class, Client.java and Server.java. Both of them extend JFrame.

In main method of my mainClass, i call :

```
Server server = new Server();
Client client = new Client();
```

I was expecting both server and client to show up, but only server shows up.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

```
public class Server extends JFrame{   
        public Server()
        {
            setTitle("Server");
            setSize(500,300);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);

            ServerSocket serverSocket;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("error found");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Client extends JFrame{

        public Client()
        {
            setTitle("Client");
            setSize(500,300);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);

            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",8000);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("error found");
            }
        }
    }


    public class Haha {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Server();
            new Client();
        }

    }
```

Haha is my main class btw. Thanks in advance!
I declarated those class in 3 different files.

Comment: Unless you post your code, there is no way we can tell you what's wrong with it.  We have no way of knowing what your classes are doing.

Comment: @azurefrog : please take a look at my edited code.

Comment: This is a rather unusal set-up. I'd sugest to split this into client and a server application. Never the less if you want to have a responsive GUI you have to understand how to use `SwingWorker` and and `invokeLater`.

Answer (score 4):

By accepting your connection in your Swing event thread, you're blocking this same thread preventing subsequent code from running. Look into using a SwingWorker to help you call blocking code in a background thread. Please check out the [SwingWorker tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more.